# simple calculation in javascript/ reference error not defined

Tags: javascript, function

I am absolutely new to javascript. I am trying to create my first html page and add some javascript on my html tags. I want to have two boxes where I can input any number and click on Show me! in order to get the result. I wrote the code below but is doesn't do anything:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interactive JS homework</title>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
        function calculate(){
            var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
            var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
            document.getElementById("result") == a+b;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="a" oninput="calculate();">
            <input type="text" id="b" oninput="calculate();">
            <input type="button" id="showme" value="Show me!" onclick="calculate();">
            <input type="text" id="result">
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Any help with where I am wrong?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the *value* property of the element. Please notice the changes in the operator used, it should be assignment (`=`) not compariosn (`==`).

```
document.getElementById("result").value = a+b;
```

I will also suggest you to assign `0` when there is no value in the element. This will prevent showing unexpected *NaN* as result if any of the element's value is empty.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interactive JS homework</title>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
        function calculate(){
            var val1 = document.getElementById("a").value.trim();
            var val2 = document.getElementById("b").value.trim();
            var a = parseFloat(val1 == ""? 0 : val1);
            var b = parseFloat(val2 == ""? 0 : val2);
            document.getElementById("result").value = a+b;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="a" oninput="calculate();">
            <input type="text" id="b" oninput="calculate();">
            <input type="button" id="showme" value="Show me!" onclick="calculate();">
            <input type="text" id="result">
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I did, but then I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment. Do you know why?

Comment: @Ioana You shouldn't get that error if you added `.value` and changed `==` to `=`

Comment: Yes. I forgot about .value. Now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you merely forgot a little thing.

When reading the values of the `a` and `b` text boxes, you correctly used `.value` after retrieving the elements to access their value, but when you tried to set the value of `result` text box, you instead just compared it to the value of `a+b`. The `==` operator is for comparison, not setting a value.

Just as well, you will need to set the `.value` of the `result` text box, instead of the text box itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interactive JS homework</title>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
        function calculate(){
            var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
            var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
            document.getElementById("result").value = a+b;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="a" oninput="calculate();">
            <input type="text" id="b" oninput="calculate();">
            <input type="button" id="showme" value="Show me!" onclick="calculate();">
            <input type="text" id="result">
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks so much! I forgot add .value to result, yes. Now it works!